# Typo in android documentation

Tags: android

Shouldn't the underlined be 'if' instead of 'is' ?[image]

Via the link for timers : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo in the Android documentation.

Comment: Dude.  You got too much time on your hands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. However, StackOverlow isn't the place to report documentation issues.

I recommend submitting a ticket to the [AOSP issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/).

Comment: did it. thanks for the link.